# Can't Change Android App Name in Settings

Tags: android, label, settings

I created an app with the wizard in ADT Eclipse. I edited the app name in strings.xml. This changed the label on the launcher icon. However if I go into Settings > Apps, it shows the old name. I tried uninstalling the app, cleaning, and running again, but it still shows the old name in settings. The old app name string does not exist in any file in the project. I don't know where it's coming from. How can I get it so that settings shows the new app name?

strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My New App Name/string>
...
</resources>
```

manifest.xml

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <activity android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
</application>
```

Comment: you try Project -> Clean ?

Comment: I also tried creating a brand new application using the wizard. Run app, the go to settings>apps and uninstall, change app_name in strings.xml, clean, run again, go to settings>app and it also shows the old name from the wizard.

Comment: I restarted the device and it updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
<activity android:name=".Main">
```

By

```
<activity
    android:name=".Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Somehow restarting the device made it work. Thanks though.

Comment: Thanks @TomKincaid it helps me to restarting the device made it work.

Comment: A simple reinstall of the app worked for me, didn't need to restart the device.