# How to change location permission dialog name?

Tags: java, android-studio, label

I have a weather app and almost done . But I want to change something before installing in google play store. Accessing user's location in my app When I first created my application, I created it with a Turkish name, but I wrote my application in English. I want to permission dialog name for example Weather app or english name not turkish. How can I fix this.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Screen shot**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BF7Z.png

**My manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.enestigli.WeatherAPP">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.HavaDurumuProjesi2"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".RecyclerView.cities" />
    <activity android:name=".Forecast.forecast" />
    <activity android:name=".AddCity.addcity" />
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Main.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**app_name in maifest file**

```
<resources>
   <string name="app_name">Weather App</string>
   <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
   <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with in the application tag add the  android:label="@string/app_name"

edit - already in user's application tag replied to thread in comments

Comment: I already tried it. You didnt see. in my manifest file dude.

Comment: APP__NAME is hitting the english name?

Comment: dude :D you can see app_name in maifest file. app_name is Weather App. Look up. How can ı change this. as far as ı understand changing the label name only changes the name in the action bar I guess but I want to change permission dialog name . Do you understand me.

Comment: i know but nothing else in the code is in the turkish name?

Comment: if not then i'm clueless and will delete the attempted answer

Comment: Yes I understand you .I say it. I changed the label names as Weather App but it steal appear HavaDurumuProjesi2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716643/cant-change-android-app-name-in-settings

suggested restarting the device....

Comment: No it didnt work

Comment: I fixed this error. I changed the name in setting gradle. setting gradle -> root name

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by following below step

- Project -> Android -> Gradle scripts -> settings.gradle -> rootProject.name